# Should the [condor] tag be updated to [htcondor]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [[condor] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/condor/info) refers to the program [HTCondor](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/). The program was originally called Condor, but changed to HTCondor [as described on the user email list in 2012](https://lists.cs.wisc.edu/archive/htcondor-users/2012-October/msg00110.shtml).

Should the tag be updated to reflect the new name?

**Edit:** As noted in a comment by @Pluto, Condor had to change its name because another software product had the name "Condor" as well.

Comment: Note the dispute over the trademark "Condor" was with this product http://www.phoenixsoftware.com/condor.htm with a basic comparison here http://www.phoenixsoftware.com/products.htm